# How to handle Firebase onAuthStateChanged in a React app and route users accordingly?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-router-dom, observer-pattern

I'm working on a React web app that is integrated with Firebase and I'm trying to authenticate my users. I have setup my route to display Home component if the user is authenticated and the Login page otherwise. But when my app first loads, it shows the Login page and it takes a second or two for it to recognize the user has actually been authenticated and then it switches to the Home page. It just seems messy and I'm guessing I'm not handling onAuthStateChanged quite well or fast enough. In my App component, I am subscribed to a ReactObserver that signals when auth state has changed. What can I do to avoid this weird behaviour?

My `App.js`:

```js
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Login from "./Login";
import {loggedIn, firebaseObserver} from "../firebase";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function App() {
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(loggedIn())

    useEffect(() => {
        firebaseObserver.subscribe('authStateChanged', data => {
            setAuthenticated(data);
        });
        return () => { firebaseObserver.unsubscribe('authStateChanged'); }
    }, []);

   return <BrowserRouter>
             <Route exact path="/" render={() => (authenticated ? <Home/> : <Login/>)} />
          </BrowserRouter>;
}
```

My `firebase.js`:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import ReactObserver from 'react-event-observer';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ...,
    authDomain: ...,
    projectId: ...,
    storageBucket: ...,
    messagingSenderId: ...,
    appId: ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const firebaseObserver = ReactObserver();

auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    firebaseObserver.publish("authStateChanged", loggedIn())
});

export function loggedIn() {
    return !!auth.currentUser;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To whom it may concern, adding a simple flag for when the authentication actually loaded solved the glitch for me. I also added protected routes (inspired by [this article](https://dev.to/pprathameshmore/protected-routes-in-react-js-216i) and I think I can continue on with my project nicely now.

`App.js`:

```js
import {BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Login from "./Login";
import {PrivateRoute} from "./PrivateRoute";
import {loggedIn, firebaseObserver} from "../firebase";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function App() {
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(loggedIn());
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        firebaseObserver.subscribe('authStateChanged', data => {
            setAuthenticated(data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
        return () => { firebaseObserver.unsubscribe('authStateChanged'); }
    }, []);

    return isLoading ? <div/> :
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <Redirect to={authenticated ? "/home" : "/login"} />
                </Route>
                <PrivateRoute path="/home" exact
                              component={Home}
                              hasAccess={authenticated} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/login" exact
                              component={Login}
                              hasAccess={!authenticated} />
                <Route path="*">
                    <Redirect to={authenticated ? "/home" : "/login"} />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>;
}
```

Comment: What is firebaseObserver? Is it some utility provided by firebase?

Comment: As shown in the question, firebaseObserver is a ReactObserver instance dedicated to this functionality, publishing auth changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `useAuthState` from `react-firebase-hooks` (https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks). This hook handles complete functionality for user auth so you don't have to setup your own context or any other function for this purpose.

**Protected routes example with `useAuthState` hook and `react-router-dom` v6**

```
import { auth } from "your-firebase-config-file-path"
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"

export const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth)

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div className="loading-component">
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

  if (user) {
    return <Outlet />
  } else {
    return <Navigate to={"/"} replace={true} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version; You can use a logged in condition to load data;

```
  /**
  * loggedIn = undefined when loading
  * loggedIn = true if loading is finished and there is a user
  * loggedIn = flase if loading is finished and there is no user
  */
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>();
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
      setLoggedIn(false);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedIn != undefined) {
      //do loggedIn stuff
    }
  }, [loggedIn]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can alternatively also use the useAuthState hook from the react-firebase-hooks library.

```
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(`${user.email} logged in!`)
    }
  }, [user])
```

Comment: This is the only and the easiest answer that helped me after hours of fiddling. I had problems where error page showed before my app recognized the firebase login and this singlehandedly solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it with a mix of the previous answers

I have component called RequireAuth to wrap the protected routes, so the router made with react router dom has the following path:

```
{
    path: "/protected",
    element: (
        <RequireAuth>
            <Protected />
        </RequireAuth>
    ),
},
```

The RequireAuth component:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../context/UserProvider";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
    const { user, validatingUser } = useContext(UserContext);

    if (validatingUser) {
        return <div />;
    }

    if (!user) {
        //user is not logged
        return <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }

    return children;
};

export default RequireAuth;
```

Then, in the /context/UserProvider we need to handle the validatingUser state:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
    onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, googleProvider } from "../config/firebase";

export const UserContext = createContext();

const UserProvider = props => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
    const [validatingUser, setValidatingUser] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unSubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
            if (user) setUser(user);
            else setUser(false);
            setValidatingUser(false); //<- here we change the validatingUser state
        });
        return () => unSubscribe();
    }, []);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider
            value={{
                user,
                validatingUser,
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default UserProvider;
```