# Can I use Firebase auth.user to get signed in user directly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a webapp using NextJS v13.4 with firebase as my backend (using the firebase web modular api). [In the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) it says

> "The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer
> on the Auth object"

I'm not entirely sure what an observer is - the closest thing I can think of in React would be a context provider that updates some state when the signed in user changes (e.g. using onAuthStateChanged as mentioned in docs).

However, I've noticed that I can also access the current user by using

```js
const auth = getAuth(app)
auth.currentUser
```

Is it bad practice to import auth into files where I want access to the current user and use auth.currentUser? If so, why? It's much simpler than writing a context provider and seems like a shortcut, so I assume there must be issues.

Finally, what is the best way to set an observe on the Auth object in react/next/typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that the user is signed in, there is nothing wrong with using `auth.currentUser` directly.

However, in any app where you want the UI to respond to the user signing in or their sign-in state being restored upon startup/reload, you will need an auth state listener to do so anyway.

In ReactJS you would typically use a one-time use-effect to attach the listener and then set the user to the state, from where the code that renders UI then picks it up.

Also see:

- [How to handle Firebase onAuthStateChanged in a React app and route users accordingly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66943220/how-to-handle-firebase-onauthstatechanged-in-a-react-app-and-route-users-accordi), specifically look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76519150/209103) which has an example using the raw Firebase JavaScript API.